# Project involving an API, a database and a visualisation package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, psycopg2

Firstly this is my first post on StackOverflow and so if I haven't structured my post properly, please let me know. Basically, I'm new to Python but I've been trying to connect an API to Python, from Python to a database that is hosted online, and then finally into a visualization package. I'm running into some problems when inserting the API data (Sheffield Solar) from Python into my database. The data does actually upload to the database but I'm struggling with an error message that I get in Python.

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pytz
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
from pandas import DataFrame
from pvlive_api import PVLive
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String, DATETIME, FLOAT


def insert_data():
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    # Calling the class from the pvlive_api.py file
    data = PVLive()
    # Gets the data between the two dates from the API and converts the output into a dataframe
    dl = data.between(datetime(2019, 4, 5, 10, 30, tzinfo=pytz.utc),
                      datetime(2020, 4, 5, 14, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc), entity_type="pes",
                      entity_id=0, dataframe=True)
    # sql is used to insert the API data into the database table
    sql = """INSERT INTO sheffield (pes_id, datetime_gmt, generation_mw) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
    uri = "Redacted"
    print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
    engine = create_engine(
        'postgresql+psycopg2://Redacted')
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    conn = psycopg2.connect(uri)
    # create a cursor that allows python code to execute Postgresql commands
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # Converts the data from a dataframe to an sql readable format, it also appends new data to the table, also
    # prevents the index from being included in the table
    into_db = dl.to_sql('sheffield', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    cur.execute(sql, into_db)
    # Commits any changes to ensure they actually happen
    conn.commit()
    # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
    cur.close()


def main():
    insert_data()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...eld (pes_id, datetime_gmt, generation_mw) VALUES (%s, %s, %s...
```

with the ^ pointing at the first %s. I'm assuming that the issue is due to me using into_db as my second argument in cur.execute(), however, as I mentioned earlier the data still uploads into my database. As I mentioned earlier I'm very new to Python and therefore it could be an easily solvable issue that I've overlooked. I've also redacted some personal connection information from the code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, please edit your post! As you can see, half of your posted code is displayed(rendered) as a string since you forgot to put closing `'` in the string passed to the `create_engine` function

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Should be sorted now, I think I accidentally deleted it when removing personal information.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting such error because trying to execute query without any values for inserting.

If you read the doc about `dl.to_sql` before using of it you would know that this method writes records to database and returns `None`.

So, there is no needed trying to construct own sql query for inserting data.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Sorry if it was a silly question but in that case should I remove the Insert Into statement and the cur.execute ?

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary, because this what  `to_sql` really doing

Comment: Thank you for the help, it’s all working properly now